Azure function corrupted modules? Works on one Function app(dev) does not on the other(client)
So I have a python v2 function app for CMS that works with the following packages(requirements.txt) -
azure-storage-blob
pytz
python-dotenv
azure-search-documents
azure-storage-file-share
aiohttp
requests
beautifulsoup4

With the function_app.py -
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
from data_process import delete_article_given_guid, index_all, process_contact_and_about, published_a_new_article
from share_function import sync_deleted_content, transfer_files
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

load_dotenv()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

@app.route(route="remove_article_by_id")
def remove_article_by_id(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(f"Remove article by ID function processed a request with with params: {req.params}")

    guid = req.params.get("guid")
    language = req.params.get("language")
    api_method = req.params.get("api_method")
    new_guid = f"{api_method}-{guid}"
    if not guid or not language or not api_method:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a guid and a language in the query string.", status_code=400
        )

    # Call the function to delete the article by GUID
    logging.info(f"Removing {api_method} article in {language}, with guid {new_guid}.")
    status_code = delete_article_given_guid(new_guid,api_method, language)
    if status_code != 200:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Article with guid {guid} not found.", status_code=status_code
        )
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Article with guid {guid} removed successfully.")


@app.route(route="publish_new_article")
def publish_new_article(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(
        f"Publish new article function received a request with params: {req.params}"
    )
    published = req.params.get("published", "false").lower() in ["true", "1", "yes"]
    api_method = req.params.get("api_method", "")
    language = req.params.get("language", "")
    id =req.params.get("id", "")
    createdDate=req.params.get("createdDate", "")
    name=req.params.get("name", "")
    

    if published and api_method and language:
        result = published_a_new_article(api_method=api_method, language=language, Article_id=id,createdDate=createdDate,name=name)

        if result == "done":
            logging.info("A new article published successfully.")
            return func.HttpResponse("New articles have been published successfully.")
        elif result == "noData":
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "No new articles found to publish.", status_code=406
            )
        else:
            logging.error(result)
            return func.HttpResponse(result, status_code=400)
    else:
        logging.error(
            "Publish action failed. Invalid paramters. Please provide valid published, api_method, and language params."
        )
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Publish action failed. Invalid paramters. Please provide valid published, api_method, and language params.",
            status_code=400,
        )
    
@app.route(route="index_all", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def index_all_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info("Processing request to index all content.")
    try:
        index_all()
        logging.info("Indexing completed successfully.")
        return func.HttpResponse("Indexing completed successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to index all content: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Failed to index all content: {str(e)}", status_code=500
        )


@app.function_name(name="index_contact_and_about")
@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 0 0 * * *", arg_name="mytimer", run_on_startup=False)
def index_contact_and_about(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    logging.info('Contact Us and About Us indexing function started')
    
    for language in ['fr-FR', 'de-DE', 'es-ES', 'ar-QA', 'en']:
        try:
            result = process_contact_and_about(language)
            if result == "error":
                logging.error(f"Failed to index Contact Us and About Us for language: {language}")
            else:
                logging.info(f"Successfully indexed Contact Us and About Us for language: {language}, {result}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception occurred while indexing Contact Us and About Us for language {language}: {e}")

With the host.json as -
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

So the issue is that it works in my dev and the same code fails in the client's production environment. On the client side, we use Azure Devops pipeline(which builds fine as I deployed the artifact on my dev env it works). With the deployment logs given below from Kudus -
{"timestamp": "2024-11-11T06:39:16.093Z", "level": "Message", "containerName": "", "machineName": "", "message": "Updating submodules."}
{"timestamp": "2024-11-11T06:39:16.275Z", "level": "Message", "containerName": "", "machineName": "", "message": "Preparing deployment for commit id '2f415e91-a'."}
{"timestamp": "2024-11-11T06:39:16.808Z", "level": "Message", "containerName": "", "machineName": "", "message": "PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False"}
{"timestamp": "2024-11-11T06:39:16.975Z", "level": "Message", "containerName": "", "machineName": "", "message": "PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot"}
{"timestamp": "2024-11-11T06:39:17.175Z", "level": "Message", "containerName": "", "machineName": "", "message": "Skipping build. Project type: Run-From-Zip"}
{"timestamp": "2024-11-11T06:39:17.335Z", "level": "Message", "containerName": "", "machineName": "", "message": "Skipping post build. Project type: Run-From-Zip"}
{"timestamp": "2024-11-11T06:39:17.568Z", "level": "Message", "containerName": "", "machineName": "", "message": "Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled)."}
{"timestamp": "2024-11-11T06:39:17.984Z", "level": "Message", "containerName": "", "machineName": "", "message": "Updating /home/data/SitePackages/packagename.txt with deployment 20241111063909.zip"}
{"timestamp": "2024-11-11T06:39:18.228Z", "level": "Message", "containerName": "", "machineName": "", "message": "Deployment successful. deployer = VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY_FUNCTIONS_V2 deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Run from package."}

The .env and configurations are nearly identical. After trying to debug it for a week using all the approaches from https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1262, It came down to this specific error log - No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public
It is very vague. So, tried to upload a simple template script to see that modules work properly -
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import sys
import os
from importlib.metadata import distributions
import json
import traceback

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize FunctionApp first
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

# Global tracking variables
services_initialized = False
initialization_error = None

# Try importing all your required services
try:
    # Import your potentially problematic modules here
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
    from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareClient
    from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    # from data_process import _index_all, delete_article_given_guid, published_a_new_article
    # from share_function import sync_deleted_content, transfer_files
    import asyncio
    import ssl
    import aiohttp
    import time
    import uuid
    import datetime
    import requests
    import pytz
    import bs4

    # Initialize your services
    load_dotenv()
    
    services_initialized = True
    logging.info("All services initialized successfully")
except Exception as e:
    initialization_error = str(e)
    logging.error(f"Initialization error: {str(e)}")
    # Don't raise the error - let functions register

@app.route(route="health", methods=["GET"])
def health(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        health_info = {
            "status": "available",
            "initialization": {
                "services_initialized": services_initialized,
                "initialization_error": initialization_error,
            },
            "environment": {
                "python_version": sys.version,
                "current_directory": os.getcwd(),
                "python_path": sys.path,
                "environment_variables": {
                    "PYTHONPATH": os.getenv("PYTHONPATH", "not set"),
                    "AzureWebJobsScriptRoot": os.getenv("AzureWebJobsScriptRoot", "not set"),
                    # Add other relevant environment variables
                    "AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT": os.getenv("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT", "not set"),
                    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": os.getenv("FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME", "not set"),
                    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": os.getenv("FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION", "not set"),
                    
                    # Storage settings
                    "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "present" if os.getenv("WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING") else "not set",
                    "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": os.getenv("WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE", "not set"),
                    
                    # Search service settings
                    "SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT": os.getenv("SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", "not set"),
                    "SEARCH_INDEX_VERSION": os.getenv("SEARCH_INDEX_VERSION", "not set"),
                    "SEARCH_API_VERSION": os.getenv("SEARCH_API_VERSION", "not set"),
                    
                    # Reports settings
                    "REPORTS_SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT": os.getenv("REPORTS_SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", "not set"),
                    "REPORTS_SEARCH_INDEX_VERSION": os.getenv("REPORTS_SEARCH_INDEX_VERSION", "not set"),
                    
                    # Container settings
                    "REPORTS_SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME": os.getenv("REPORTS_SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME", "not set"),
                    "REPORTS_TARGET_CONTAINER_NAME": os.getenv("REPORTS_TARGET_CONTAINER_NAME", "not set"),
                    
                    # API settings
                    "UMBRACO_API_URL": os.getenv("UMBRACO_API_URL", "not set"),
                    "MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": os.getenv("MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS", "not set")
                },
            },
            "azure_services": {
                "blob_storage": "available" if "BlobServiceClient" in globals() else "not imported",
                "file_share": "available" if "ShareClient" in globals() else "not imported",
                "search_client": "available" if "SearchClient" in globals() else "not imported",
                "data_process": {
                    "_index_all": "available" if "_index_all" in globals() else "not imported",
                    "delete_article": "available" if "delete_article_given_guid" in globals() else "not imported",
                    "publish_article": "available" if "published_a_new_article" in globals() else "not imported"
                },
                "share_function": {
                    "sync_deleted_content": "available" if "sync_deleted_content" in globals() else "not imported",
                    "transfer_files": "available" if "transfer_files" in globals() else "not imported"
                }
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "installed_packages": [f"{dist.metadata['Name']}=={dist.version}" for dist in distributions()]
            }
        }

        return func.HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(health_info, indent=2),
            mimetype="application/json"
        )
    except Exception as e:
        error_info = {
            "status": "error",
            "error_type": type(e).__name__,
            "error_message": str(e),
            "error_traceback": traceback.format_exc(),
        }
        logging.error(f"Health check failed: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(error_info, indent=2),
            status_code=500,
            mimetype="application/json"
        )

This also failed. This leads me to think it is due to corrupted modules, any idea how to resolve it as the client refuses to make another resource? How to remove the old corrupted modules.
NOTE #1: The code works in 2 of my dev Azure functions.
NOTE #2: It shows successfully deployed but has no functions on the overview also files are not visible.

Are you able to see the functions in overview post dev deployment?

@IkhtesamAfrin No I can't see them. The old un-updated functions are visible with an error - "We are not able to load some functions in the list due to errors. Refresh the page to try again". Also clicking on them shows an error and cant be viewed

You need to have the given packages in requirements.txt file.
azure-functions
requests
azure-storage-file-share
azure-storage-blob
python-dotenv
azure-search-documents
aiohttp
pytz
bs4

I am using your second code which gives the number of imported modules.
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import sys
import os
from importlib.metadata import distributions
import json
import traceback

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize FunctionApp first
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

# Global tracking variables
services_initialized = False
initialization_error = None

# Try importing all your required services
try:
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
    from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareClient
    from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    import asyncio
    import ssl
    import aiohttp
    import time
    import uuid
    import datetime
    import requests
    import pytz
    import bs4

    # Initialize your services
    load_dotenv()
    
    services_initialized = True
    logging.info("All services initialized successfully")
except Exception as e:
    initialization_error = str(e)
    logging.error(f"Initialization error: {str(e)}")
    # Don't raise the error - let functions register

@app.route(route="health", methods=["GET"])
def health(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        health_info = {
            "status": "available",
            "initialization": {
                "services_initialized": services_initialized,
                "initialization_error": initialization_error,
            },
            "environment": {
                "python_version": sys.version,
                "current_directory": os.getcwd(),
                "python_path": sys.path,
                "environment_variables": {
                    "PYTHONPATH": os.getenv("PYTHONPATH", "not set"),
                    "AzureWebJobsScriptRoot": os.getenv("AzureWebJobsScriptRoot", "not set"),
                    # Add other relevant environment variables
                    "AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT": os.getenv("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT", "not set"),
                    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": os.getenv("FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME", "not set"),
                    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": os.getenv("FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION", "not set"),
                    
                    # Storage settings
                    "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "present" if os.getenv("WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING") else "not set",
                    "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": os.getenv("WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE", "not set"),
                    
                    # Search service settings
                    "SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT": os.getenv("SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", "not set"),
                    "SEARCH_INDEX_VERSION": os.getenv("SEARCH_INDEX_VERSION", "not set"),
                    "SEARCH_API_VERSION": os.getenv("SEARCH_API_VERSION", "not set"),
                    
                    # Reports settings
                    "REPORTS_SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT": os.getenv("REPORTS_SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", "not set"),
                    "REPORTS_SEARCH_INDEX_VERSION": os.getenv("REPORTS_SEARCH_INDEX_VERSION", "not set"),
                    
                    # Container settings
                    "REPORTS_SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME": os.getenv("REPORTS_SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME", "not set"),
                    "REPORTS_TARGET_CONTAINER_NAME": os.getenv("REPORTS_TARGET_CONTAINER_NAME", "not set"),
                    
                    # API settings
                    "UMBRACO_API_URL": os.getenv("UMBRACO_API_URL", "not set"),
                    "MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": os.getenv("MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS", "not set")
                },
            },
            "azure_services": {
                "blob_storage": "available" if "BlobServiceClient" in globals() else "not imported",
                "file_share": "available" if "ShareClient" in globals() else "not imported",
                "search_client": "available" if "SearchClient" in globals() else "not imported",
                "data_process": {
                    "_index_all": "available" if "_index_all" in globals() else "not imported",
                    "delete_article": "available" if "delete_article_given_guid" in globals() else "not imported",
                    "publish_article": "available" if "published_a_new_article" in globals() else "not imported"
                },
                "share_function": {
                    "sync_deleted_content": "available" if "sync_deleted_content" in globals() else "not imported",
                    "transfer_files": "available" if "transfer_files" in globals() else "not imported"
                }
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "installed_packages": [f"{dist.metadata['Name']}=={dist.version}" for dist in distributions()]
            }
        }

        return func.HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(health_info, indent=2),
            mimetype="application/json"
        )
    except Exception as e:
        error_info = {
            "status": "error",
            "error_type": type(e).__name__,
            "error_message": str(e),
            "error_traceback": traceback.format_exc(),
        }
        logging.error(f"Health check failed: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(error_info, indent=2),
            status_code=500,
            mimetype="application/json"
        )

Try to execute the code locally first before deploying. I can see the function in overview tab post deployment.



Tried, works fine on local and Azure function dev environment. But fails on the client prod environment (as in no error during deployment but cannot view function).

In which way you are deploying it to dev, using pipeline?

No, In dev using Azure Functions Core Tools (oryx build). In client prod using pipeline.

Try adding SCM_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=1 and ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD=true in Environment variable of function before deployment

Added these to .env on client prod, the same results. So I believe the build happens in the azure pipeline and we just upload the zip on the client prod function app.

You need to add these variables here

Yup done that... Is there any way to remove the python modules cache or reset the function(Client won't assign me a new resource). I have a strong feeling it is due to corrupted files.

Try to execute pip uninstall -r requirements.txt command

The DevOps told me that is not possible. Could you tell me anything about this error. https://imgur.com/a/CVSBFYn

Can you share the exact error, I can see you have shared a list of exceptions types

Unable to get table reference or create table. Aborting write operation.
This request is not authorized to perform this operation. RequestId:4d6c64db-e002-0026-56b6-3116ed000000 Time:2024-11-08T08:12:52.4394581Z Status: 403 (Forbidden) ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure Content: {'odata.error':{'code':'AuthorizationFailure',

'message':{'lang':'en-US','value':'This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:4d6c64db-e002-0026-56b6-3116ed000000\nTime:2024-11-08T08:12:52.4394581Z'}}} Headers: Transfer-Encoding: chunked Server: Windows-Azure-Table/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 x-ms-request-id: 4d6c64db-e002-0026-56b6-3116ed000000 x-ms-client-request-id: 4aec1e5d-a629-49fe-870d-4ffaa5dc796f x-ms-version: REDACTED X-Content-Type-Options: REDACTED Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2024 08:12:52 GMT Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8

It looks like you don't have required permission to perform the activity which you are doing currently.

I have an old function saved without said updates, when I deploy it, it still works. But when I now upload the updated file only it fails. .env stays the same throughout. –

How are you uploading?

Through pipeline both. Obviously I added new dependencies too in the new version

is it possible for you to try on a new function app?

On the client side I am restricted and won't allow to create a function. On my dev env it works.

I believe you don't have the required permission thats why you are getting forbidden error
